# Via GraphQL - CRUD on public/private metafields on a product

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app

Is there anyway I could either update or delete a public metafield in a product, or a process to create and retrieve a private metafield via GraphQL?

Comment: The documentation is a little unclear here regarding public vs private metafields. It has the headings Creating metafields, Retrieving metafields, Updating private metafields, Deleting private metafields. I don't know the answer, but your question seems justified. https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-metafields-with-graphql-admin-api (also, welcome to StackOverflow!)

Comment: Yeah this is what I kept stumbling around when trying to solve this, I'm still digging for a solid solution but hopefully will land on something soon (Thank you very much!)

Answer (score -1):

Certainly. As long as you own the API key that created the private Metafield, you can easily make changes to it. The mutations to alter private Metafields on resources are published.

Comment: Thank you Makyen for editing this comment - the tone of the original answer is the reason I tend to avoid asking questions on here. However I appreciate the response from both, I feel I may not have fleshed out the question as much as I should have - the app I am working to intends to mutate a public field in a similar manner to how the Metafield Guru app does. From my understanding it is not possible to directly edit public metafields, and the reason I was asking about private metafields was because I was also looking for a way to expose them and then potentially attach them to a product